# Laravel 5.2 + Socialite + Update Status

Tags: laravel, authentication, hybridauth, laravel-socialite

Well, for quite some time now, i've been doing some research on which plugin to use in Laravel 5.2 for the purpose of authenticating users in my website via their social networks accounts.

I wanted to use Hybridauth, but it is not compatible with Laravel 5.2, it is compatible only with Laravel 4.2. So, i was thinking of using Socialite, but the thing is that i want to give my user the ability to post his social network status via my own website.

So, is there a way that i could give my user this ability using Socialite?

Comment: You are asking: "Is there any package for Laravel that does this: [inserts all requirements]". In my opinion this is not a good written question. Read the how to ask a question section on stack overflow, to improve it.

Comment: @henrik 
I've made my question more brief, and just to clarify, i meant that, using socialite with laravel 5.2, would i be able to update my user's status on his behalf like "Hybridauth"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel Socialite handles authentication only.

You can get an access token for the various social media APIs using socialite, but the package does not offer any methods for interacting with those APIs.

If you want your user to be able to post to social media accounts you will need to write the code to interact with those APIs for use a package which provides that functionality, but it is beyond the scope of Socialite.

Comment: Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @GesdevWebdev if you're happy with the answer, please accept it. Thanks.